# Winforms - what's a cool taskbar/system tray notifier approach?

Tags: wpf, winforms, notifications, taskbar, system-tray

What's a cool taskbar/system tray notifier approach?  To get that latest cool looking sliding windows type notifications can I stay WinForms, or do I need to go WFP?  Which control/class/framework should I look at?

Basically after a more fresher:modern looking UI than the old winforms popular bubbles etc

Answer (score 0):

This might be interesting for you: [When to adopt WPF](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/when-to-adopt-wpf.aspx).

But personally I'd not change the UI to be cool looking and sliding. Try to be consistent to Windows.